# MySql Query- Date Range within a Date Range

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I use mySql 5 and IIS.
I have `products`, that have a `start date` field and an `end date` field.

I need to run a query that will take user entered Start and End dates, and output the number of days that the product ran within the date range.

Example:

```
Offer1 - July 1 2011 thru July 31 2011
Query - July 1 2011 thru Sept 15 2011
```

Results = 31

```
Example:
Offer1 - July 1 2011 thru July 31 2011
Query - July 1 2011 thru July 15 2011
```

Results = 15

Answer (score 4):

If your `products` have a `start_date` and an `end_date` and your query has a `qstart_date` and a `qend_date`, then we want the number of days between:

```
GREATEST(start_date, qstart_date)
```

and

```
LEAST(end_date,qend_date)
```

. In MySQL I think this looks like

```
1 + DATEDIFF ( 'd' , GREATEST(start_date, qstart_date) , LEAST(end_date,qend_date) )
```

And you'll want to ignore negative numbers, replacing them with "0".

Comment: +1: Could also wrap the DATEDIFF in `ABS` if the start & end get reversed.

Comment: @Chris: You also need to add +1 to this result. As it is, you'll get `31-1 = 30`

Comment: @OMG Ponies We can't use `ABS` because then we will mess up sometimes and think that there were some overlaps. Negative numbers here mean "nope, the date ranges didn't overlap; they missed by this much."