# Mysql... a price range within a price range?

Tags: php, mysql, range, between

I am developing a real estate script. The script has a search option where an user can specify the price range eg. user_price_low to user_price_high and the listings have to be fetched from a database, which has eg. db_price_high and db_price_low.

I used a BETWEEN statement trying to find the matches,

```
WHERE price_low BETWEEN '.$_REQUEST['minprice_buy'].' AND '.$_REQUEST['maxprice_buy']
```

but to my surprise...

If an user has user_price_high = 60 and user_price_low = 20
AND
the record has db_price_low = 30 and db_price_high = 120

my query is invalid in this case.

i tried looking at [MySql Query- Date Range within a Date Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589079/mysql-query-date-range-within-a-date-range) but does that match what I want?

Comment: Another php post, another SQL-injection.

Comment: what do you mean the db has a `price_low` and `price_high`? Shouldn't it just have a `price`? Show more code along with your db table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chandan, never ever input $_* functions directly into a query. It's an SQL-injection hole.

Change the code to:

```
$min_price = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['minprice_buy']);
$max_price = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['maxprice_buy']);
$query = "SELECT whatever 
          FROM whichever 
          WHERE price_low BETWEEN '$min_price' AND '$max_price' ";
// Dont forget these quotes       ^          ^     ^          ^
// Or mysql_real_escape_string() will not work!.
```

With regards to your question, change the query to something like:

```
WHERE '$min_price' BETWEEN price_low AND price_high 
  AND '$max_price' BETWEEN price_low AND price_high
```

You may also want to consider:

```
WHERE ('$min_price' BETWEEN price_low AND price_high) 
  OR  ('$max_price' BETWEEN price_low AND price_high)
```

Here `min_price` and `max_price` don't need to both be in the range at all times.

See: [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)

Comment: Your answer isn't quite right, I don't think. It needs to be inclusive (OR), not exclusive (AND).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I tried putting in the query as you suggested and everything seems to be working fine. However I will test it a bit more to make sure that there are no more bugs. I appriciate you also reminded me about the SQL Injection. However I did the check by $_REQUEST['minprice_buy'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['minprice_buy']); Wont that be fine?

Comment: That's just complication stuff for no reason, I recommend code like above, it's much easier to read and understand. Besides there's no need to reject the code beforehand, let the query run, otherwise an attacker will know what you're testing for by examining the timing differences in your code and focussing his attack on the code that took longer to return i.e. the code where you forgot to put in the test.

Comment: Great! Now what happens when  user_low = 80, user_high = 200      and    db_low = 64, db_high = 121     doesnt that listing fall in the range?  Meaning the builder has got a flat with him within that range right? We were thinking of something where we check both ways. WHERE (user_low between db_low AND db_high) OR (user_high BETWEEN db_high AND db_low) OR (db_low BETWEEN user_low AND user_high) OR (db_high BETWEEN user_low AND user_high)

Comment: @chandan, if you want a match on **that**, then use the last option in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if ranges have any common points you should use

```
WHERE greatest(price_low,user_price_low)<=least(price_high,user_price_high)
```

If you want to check if user range is in all range you may use
**Undefined behaviour for `user_preice_low>user_price_high`**

```
WHERE user_price_low>=price_low && user_price_high<=price_high
```

Comment: in SQL the max() function does not work like that, you need to use the greatest() function. And if `user_price_low = 50000 and user_price_high = 1`, your query will return true, even though the values do not fall inside the range.

Comment: @Johan: function names are fixed. for `user_price_low = 50000 and user_price_high = 1` res first query will ok. Second  query will return some rows, but It may be checked on client( I will add info)

Comment: I dropped the -1, because the top line is correct, however the bottom line is not. Note that using a function will kill any chance of using an index. Which will not make for happy queries.

Answer (score -2):

so accourding to what i understand, shouldnt it be

```
WHERE price_low >= '.$_REQUEST['minprice_buy'].' AND price_high <='.$_REQUEST['maxprice_buy']'
```

Validate your Input using `mysql_real_escape_string();` before using them in the query, dont use $_GET, $_REQUEST, $_POST variables directly in any query.

Comment: -1, you cannot leave a glaring SQL injection hole in an answer like that and expect to get upvotes. Oh and the answer is incorrect `WHERE X >= MIN AND y <= max` does not guarantee that (min < max).

Comment: @Johan why should one guarantee that (min<max) in this case ?

Comment: Because if Min = 50000 and Max = 1, neither of them falls within the range.

Comment: @Johan isnt it safe to assume that (min<max), Min = 50000 and Max = 1 doesnt makes any sense, and should return no results, i am probably failing to see a practical example :-/